# Creating service with short Name and DisplayName breaks WMI for services

Tags: windows, windows-services, wmi, get-wmiobject

Lately I was having problem with WMI on one of the systems (win server 2019). Service list in Task Manager was empty and running `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service` from powershell was returning `Generic failure`.  After fruitless hours of searching and trying to repair system I gave up and was ready to reinstall system. Then error was reproduced on another machine by accident and I was able to narrow down cause of the problem. After creating windows service with short name and short display name WMI brakes after system restart but only if that service is first (in alphanumeric order) on services list. To reproduce this effect you only need to run

`sc create "A1" binpath="D:\foobar.exe" DisplayName="A1" start=disabled`

`binpath` is irrelevant, service doesn't need to be started. `DisplayName` doesn't need to be identical to name. After that command you need to restart (before restart everything works). After that if you go to services list in task manager it will be empty (probably using WMI to query services list). Now you can run `sc delete "A1"` and reopen task manager. Everything is back to normal.

Problem was reproduced on Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10 (didn't tried on other versions).

Is this a known bug or what is happening here?

EDIT
I'm not asking about how to use `sc`. It's doesn't matter. I provided commands that someone can run to reproduce problem. You can create service with that parameters however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the sc command line arguments in the incorrect format.
From [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe):

> Optionvalue

Specifies the value for the parameter named by Optionname. See the Optionname reference for a list of supported values. When a string is to be input, the use of empty quotes means that an empty string is passed in. **Note that there is a space between OptionValue and the equal sign**.

The correct command should be:

```
sc create "A1" binpath= "D:\foobar.exe" DisplayName= "A1" start= disabled
```

Comment: How is this related to my question? Furthermore in documentation that you bring up you can read that "Note that there is no space between the Optionname and the equal sign"? I don't have problem with executing sc command

Comment: Read the documentation carefully and get to the section "Note that there is a space between OptionValue and the equal sign". If you are using the command line in a wrong way, dont you think it's a way to start analyzing the problem?

Comment: Look for a string that I posted and the example.

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about. You command will always return error. Did you even run that? 
This is not question about `sc`, you can create service with given parameters however you want. I'm asking why WMI breake, not how to use `sc`